# Converting a propositional formula to conjunctive normal form

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am supposed to convert the following formula into CNF

(¬a ∧ (b ∨ ¬c)) ↔ (⊥ ∧ ((a → ¬ (b ∨ ¬c)) ∨ T))

This subject is new to me so I find the conversion difficult, namely, where do you start? Do you first break down the equivalence into implications and then tackle the remaining parts or vice versa?

Also, I do not understand why the right side of the equivalence doesn't just cancel out?

(⊥ ∧ ((a → ¬ (b ∨ ¬c)) ∨ T))

I think of it as "Bottom and ([something] or Top)" which is always true?

P.s. apologies if my question/formatting is confusing. I am new to the forum.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g*., [basic help on mathjax notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), [main meta site math tutorial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68388/there-should-be-universal-latex-mathjax-guide-for-sites-supporting-it/70559#70559), and [equation editing how-to](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto).

Comment: Too complicated... choose a simpler example for practice.

Comment: Having said that, NO $\bot$ is always False and thus $(\bot \land \text { whatever } ) \equiv \bot$

Comment: Thus, we are reduced it to the much more manegeable: $(¬a ∧ (b ∨ ¬c)) ↔ ⊥$ that is $(¬a ∧ (b ∨ ¬c)) → ⊥] ∧ [⊥ → (\ldots)]$

Comment: The second part of the formula is $[¬⊥ ∨ (\ldots)] \equiv [\top \lor (\ldots)] \equiv \top$

Comment: The first part will be $¬ [(¬a∧(b∨¬c))]$

Comment: Could you specify this part?
The second part of the formula is  [¬⊥∨(…)]≡[⊤∨(…)]≡⊤